# Solution of a recurrence relation

Tags: difference-equations

I want to solve $a_{n+1} = (1 + \alpha) a_n + \gamma$, where $\alpha$ and $\gamma$ are some constants. Wolfram alpha returns:

$a_n = \frac{\gamma ((1+\alpha)^n-1)}{\alpha} + c (1+\alpha)^{n-1}$.

Any idea how Wolfram alpha has solved this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think CASes apply a usual method of solving linear recurrence relations with constant coefficients (for example, see [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_recurrence_with_constant_coefficients) for info). In any case the result of the command of Maple

```
infolevel[all] := 4: rsolve(a(n+1) = k*a(n)+b, a(n));
```

confirms that guess.

Addition. As step-by-step solution by W|A shows, the generating function is used to this end there.

Addition 2. See [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/z6xf14ygqjl9xcu/%D0%97%D0%BD%D1%96%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BA%20%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0%202022-09-27%2016.28.13.png?dl=0)
and [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/vfvka76tj9filzo/%D0%97%D0%BD%D1%96%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BA%20%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0%202022-09-27%2016.28.33.png?dl=0) and [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/lycg09rlndk4u3q/%D0%97%D0%BD%D1%96%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BA%20%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0%202022-09-27%2016.28.45.png?dl=0).

Comment: @Martin: As an exception, I added screens to my answer.

Answer (score 3):

```
$Version

(* "13.1.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (June 16, 2022)" *)

WolframAlpha["step-by-step solve a[n+1]==(1+α) a[n]+γ"]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

```
Clear[a, \[Alpha], n]
RSolve[a[n + 1] == (1 + α) a[n] + γ, a[n], n]
```

$$\left\{\left\{a(n)\to -\frac{\gamma  \left(1-(\alpha +1)^n\right)}{\alpha }+c_1 (\alpha +1)^{n-1}\right\}\right\}$$

---

**EDIT**

For a step-by-step solution type <kbd>=</kbd><kbd>=</kbd> and paste equation into Mathematica:

[image]

Comment: May be Wolfram alpha can provide the step by step solution but I don't know the command for that.

Comment: Updated the answer. It is quite a series of steps to get there.